# This Code is overwriting my Theme Container Space (style.css?

Tags: html, css

I designed a template ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iukB.jpg)) using Thrive Architect for footer. I embed all the source code in footer using hooks.

But there is some code in that template that overwrites my *style.css*, and changed my theme layout from this ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PkFq.jpg)) to this ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6WC.jpg)). I tried my best to find that code that overwrites my theme code but I failed.

Here is the template's source code that overwrites my theme style.css -

```
<style type="text/css" class="tve_custom_style">@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700,300,600,900&subset=latin");@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700,700i,600,600i,500,500i,300,300i,200,200i&subset=latin");@media (min-width: 300px){[data-css="tve-u-16209398a6a"] { margin-top: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-1620938d6b3"] { padding-bottom: 0px ; padding-top: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-1620938d6b3"] > .tcb-flex-col > .tcb-col { justify-content: center; }[data-css="tve-u-16209362d2a"] { max-width: 1080px; min-height: 311px ; }[data-css="tve-u-16209354f5c"] { background-color: rgb(231, 237, 243) ; }[data-css="tve-u-1620935170d"] { padding: 33px 0px 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161fae5c8ba"] > .tcb-flex-col > .tcb-col { min-height: 123px; }[data-css="tve-u-161fae5c8ba"] { margin-left: -14px; min-height: inherit; padding-bottom: 0px ; padding-top: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161fae5c8ba"] > .tcb-flex-col { padding-left: 14px; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161e7579958"]:hover button { background-color: rgb(35, 154, 195) ; box-shadow: rgba(14, 58, 74, 0.08) 0px 0px 8px 4px ; font-size: 16px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161ec22418e"] { float: none; display: block; z-index: 3; position: relative; margin: 0px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e468d33f"] { max-width: 26.1%; }[data-css="tve-u-161e468d335"] { max-width: 73.9%; }#tcb_landing_page h6 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h5 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h4 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h6 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(28, 28, 28); font-size: 20px; }#tcb_landing_page h5 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(28, 28, 28); font-size: 21px; }#tcb_landing_page h4 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(28, 28, 28); font-size: 23px; }#tcb_landing_page h3 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h3 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(42, 169, 213); font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.3em; }#tcb_landing_page h2 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h2 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(28, 28, 28); font-size: 48px; line-height: 1.3em; }#tcb_landing_page h1 strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page h1 { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; font-size: 58px; line-height: 1.3em; color: rgb(16, 25, 41); }#tcb_landing_page p strong, #tcb_landing_page li strong { font-weight: 700; }#tcb_landing_page p, #tcb_landing_page li { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.6em; color: rgb(28, 28, 28); }[data-css="tve-u-15e09c94f7d"] { background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }[data-css="tve-u-161e53b0db1"] h3 { margin: 0px 0px 14px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e53b0db1"] h1 { margin: 0px 0px 18px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e53b0db1"] h2 { margin: 0px 0px 16px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e53b0db1"] p { margin: 0px 0px 24px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e53b0db1"] { max-width: 1080px; min-height: 146px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e54443dc"] { padding: 18px 20px 80px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161e7579958"] button { font-size: 25px; border-radius: 54px; overflow: hidden; font-weight: 400; font-family: Nunito; background-color: rgb(42, 169, 213) ; padding: 15px 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] strong { font-weight: 700; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input { font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 300; font-size: 17px; border-radius: 54px; overflow: hidden; padding: 22px ; background-image: none ; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ; }#tcb_landing_page .thrv_text_element a:hover, #tcb_landing_page .tcb-styled-list a:hover, #tcb_landing_page .tcb-numbered-list a:hover { color: rgb(42, 169, 213); font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; }#tcb_landing_page .thrv_text_element a, #tcb_landing_page .tcb-styled-list a, #tcb_landing_page .tcb-numbered-list a { color: rgb(16, 25, 41); text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; }[data-css="tve-u-1714841b19c"] { height: 105px; bottom: 0px; fill: rgb(0, 105, 211); }[data-css="tve-u-162094bb60a"] { padding-right: 50px ; padding-left: 50px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-17148468562"] { color: rgb(42, 169, 213) ; font-size: 28px ; }[data-css="tve-u-171484727d0"] { padding: 0px ; margin-left: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-171484ffb94"] { margin: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-17148500971"] { padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-17148505096"] { padding: 0px 77px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input, :not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] select { font-size: 16px; font-family: Nunito; padding: 15px 22px ; margin-top: 10px ; margin-bottom: 10px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] { display: inline-block; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input, :not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input::placeholder, :not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] select { font-weight: 300 ; }[data-css="tve-u-171485fd231"] { padding: 0px ; margin-left: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-1714864f524"] { background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 105, 211), rgb(0, 105, 211)) ; background-size: auto ; background-position: 50% 50% ; background-attachment: scroll ; background-repeat: no-repeat ; }[data-css="tve-u-17148e37268"] { min-height: inherit; }[data-css="tve-u-17148e37268"] > .tcb-flex-col > .tcb-col { min-height: 195px; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-17148fc6e7f"] { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ; font-size: 20px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-1714902a832"] { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ; font-size: 20px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-1714902c3d7"] { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ; font-size: 20px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-1714904ac21"] { color: rgb(234, 234, 234) ; font-size: 17px ; font-family: Nunito ; font-weight: 400 ; }}@media (max-width: 1023px){:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161e7579958"] button { font-size: 16px; }[data-css="tve-u-1620938d6b3"] > .tcb-flex-col > .tcb-col { justify-content: flex-end; }[data-css="tve-u-1620938d6b3"] .tcb-flex-col { flex-basis: 332px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161ec22418e"] { margin-bottom: 0px ; margin-right: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-171485fd231"] { padding: 1px 66px ; }}@media (max-width: 767px){[data-css="tve-u-162094bb60a"] { text-align: left; padding: 0px 11px ; }[data-css="tve-u-16209398a6a"] { text-align: left; }[data-css="tve-u-161fae5c8ba"] > .tcb-flex-col > .tcb-col { min-height: 20px; }[data-css="tve-u-161fae5c8ba"] { min-height: inherit; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input { margin-bottom: 10px ; padding-bottom: 22px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161ec22418e"] { margin-bottom: 20px ; margin-top: 0px ; padding: 0px ; }[data-css="tve-u-161e54443dc"] { padding-left: 10px ; padding-right: 10px ; }[data-css="tve-u-17148505096"] { padding-right: 11px ; padding-left: 11px ; }[data-css="tve-u-171485fd231"] { padding-right: 5px ; padding-left: 5px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-17148468562"] { font-size: 22px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-17148605010"] { font-size: 16px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] input, :not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161fafb10ca"] select { padding-top: 12px ; padding-bottom: 12px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-161e7579958"] button { text-transform: none; padding-top: 12px ; padding-bottom: 12px ; }[data-css="tve-u-16209362d2a"] { min-height: 411px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-17148fc6e7f"] { font-size: 22px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-1714902a832"] { font-size: 22px ; }:not(#tve) [data-css="tve-u-1714902c3d7"] { font-size: 22px ; }}
    </style>
```

Now, How to find that?

The Added !important in style.css of theme -

```
.separate-containers .inside-article,
.separate-containers .comments-area,
.separate-containers .page-header,
.separate-containers .paging-navigation,
.one-container .site-content,
.inside-page-header,
.wp-block-group__inner-container {
    padding: 40px !important;
}

.separate-containers .widget,
.separate-containers .site-main > *,
.separate-containers .page-header,
.widget-area .main-navigation {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.separate-containers .site-main {
    margin: 20px !important;
}

.no-sidebar.separate-containers .site-main {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.right-sidebar.separate-containers .site-main,
.both-right.separate-containers .site-main {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.left-sidebar.separate-containers .site-main,
.both-left.separate-containers .site-main {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.both-right.separate-containers .inside-left-sidebar,
.both-left.separate-containers .inside-left-sidebar {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.both-right.separate-containers .inside-right-sidebar,
.both-left.separate-containers .inside-right-sidebar {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}

.separate-containers .inside-right-sidebar,
.separate-containers .inside-left-sidebar {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.separate-containers .page-header-image,
.separate-containers .page-header-contained,
.separate-containers .page-header-image-single,
.separate-containers .page-header-content-single {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Use !important in your stylesheet to override the existing styles.

Comment: I added but didn't work.

Comment: can you share a part of that code where you are applying !important?

Comment: I added that code in the question.